# Error messages while running update manager

Tags: 12.04, update-manager

Running 12.04 32 bit Ubuntu. I have updates that need to be installed. When I try to download and install the updates using the update manager, I get the following errors:

```
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gnupg/gpgv_1.4.11-3ubuntu2.1_i386.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.190 80]
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gnupg/gnupg_1.4.11-3ubuntu2.1_i386.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.190 80]
Failed to fetch http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/pool/main/g/google-chrome-stable/google-chrome-stable_23.0.1271.97-r171054_i386.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 74.125.225.128 80]
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/multiverse/f/flashplugin-nonfree/flashplugin-installer_11.2.202.258ubuntu0.12.04.1_i386.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/g/gnupg/gnupg-curl_1.4.11-3ubuntu2.1_i386.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.190 80]
```

What do I need to do to fix this?

Comment: `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade -y` again.